# Can't workout why TablePlus refuses to connect to db with Sail 0n 3307

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am running using Sail for my side project, and use Homestead for work.
I get conflicts with port 3306, so I moved Sail to 3307, but now for some reason I can't get TablePlus to connect to the DB.
Just to be clear, the site loads in the browser and `sail tinker`, `sail artisan:migrate` both work fine, it's JUST TablePlus that isn't working?!
It worked fine last weekend when I was using it, but after getting the issue with something using `3306` I decided to change the port to `3307`
I've run `docker-compose down -v` to delete the volume including the db, and brought it back up, and the site works after a migration, but still nothing with TP.
The following is my `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tall_events
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
mysql:
 image: "mysql:8.0"
 ports:
      - "${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3307"
 environment:
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
 MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
 MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
 MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
 MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
 volumes:
      - "sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

It's showing as port `3307` on Docker Desktop:
[image]

But when I try to connect with TablePlus on `3307` I get the following:
[image]

And when I try `3306` I get
[image]

Comment: `"${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3307"` the internal port should be 3306

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sail up -d` docker-compose creates a virtual network. With your existing config, mysql is still listening on port 3306 on that virtual network, but in the `docker-compose.yml` you're mapping port 3307 on you machine to 3307 on the mysql container.

What you need to do is map port 3307 on your machine to port 3306 on the mysql container. To do that, you can update the ports section of your `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```yaml
mysql:
 ports:
   - "3307:3306"
```

This means you can connect to `localhost:3307` with TablePlus, but your Laravel app, which is running in a docker container connected to the virtual network, can still connect to `mysql:3306` on that virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

Check your host in TablePlus.

In your .env file, the DB_HOST is "mysql".
The host in TablePlus looks like it's set to "127.0.0.1"

Also, check the database name.  It looks like it's set to "da"-something, when it should be "tall_events"